# SQL selecting from multiple tables to show even null values

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have 3 tables which have foreign key **ACCOUNT_NO**, first table is **CREDIT_LIST** which holds all the credits taken from bank, second table is **CUSTOMERS** which holds customer info, and the last is **ACCOUNTS** which holds all the info about account itself. When I try to select

```
SELECT 
    B.CUSTOMER_NO AS CUSTOMER_NO,
    B.CREDIT_TYPE AS CREDIT_TYPE,
    B.ACCOUNT_NO AS CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    A.BRANCH_CODE AS BRANCH_CODE,
    C.EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NO AS EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM 
    CREDIT_LIST B,
    CUSTOMERS A,
    ACCOUNTS C
WHERE   
    B.STATUS = 'A' -- ACTIVE
    AND A.CUSTOMER_NO = B.CUSTOMER_NO
    AND C.ACCOUNT_NO = B.ACCOUNT_NO
    ;
```

I get zero results because there is no `EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NO` in **ACCOUNTS** which has the `c.account_no = b.account_no`. The problem is that I want to show the info even if there is no `EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NO` and fill it with null for example:

```
| CUSTOMER_NO | CREDIT_TYPE | CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER | BRANCH_CODE | EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------------+------------------------
|     1       | some_type   | 123456                | 01          | 
|     2       | some_type   | 654321                | 01          | 111111111111
```

I feel like this is extremely stupid but can't figure out what exactly I am doing wrong

Comment: Use explicit joins and not the antiquated old style joins

Comment: And then use `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is what you need

```
SELECT 
    B.CUSTOMER_NO AS CUSTOMER_NO,
    B.CREDIT_TYPE AS CREDIT_TYPE,
    B.ACCOUNT_NO AS CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    A.BRANCH_CODE AS BRANCH_CODE,
    C.EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NO AS EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM 
    CREDIT_LIST B
    JOIN     CUSTOMERS A on A.CUSTOMER_NO = B.CUSTOMER_NO
    LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS C on C.ACCOUNT_NO = B.ACCOUNT_NO
WHERE   
    B.STATUS = 'A' -- ACTIVE
;
```

The left join will make sure, you get details from A and B, even when there is no data available in C.

Also the `AS` is redundant, not really required, you can just write `B.ACCOUNT_NO CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER` in line 4 of the query.

Left Outer Join - [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html)

Not Suggested, however, if there is a reason, you need to use the old syntax, below is what you need

```
SELECT 
    B.CUSTOMER_NO AS CUSTOMER_NO,
    B.CREDIT_TYPE AS CREDIT_TYPE,
    B.ACCOUNT_NO AS CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
    A.BRANCH_CODE AS BRANCH_CODE,
    C.EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NO AS EXTERNAL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM 
    CREDIT_LIST B,
    CUSTOMERS A,
    ACCOUNTS C
WHERE   
    B.STATUS = 'A' -- ACTIVE
    AND A.CUSTOMER_NO = B.CUSTOMER_NO
    AND C.ACCOUNT_NO(+) = B.ACCOUNT_NO -- (+) will do a outer join for you
    ;
```

Comment: personally I find the `AS` keyword helpful when defining column aliases, and I wish Oracle supported it for table aliases too.

Comment: then does `a1 join a2 on a1.id = a2.id` is same with `select * from a1, a2 where a1.id = a2.id`?

Comment: @Hatik - Yes. another way you can do the same is, `select * from a1 join a2 using (id);` if the column names are same, I prefer `using (column_name)`